# Solving a simple differential equation and plotting the solution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm still a beginner at Mathematica and I don't know how to solve problems or plot solutions. I have this equation:

$\qquad dP(t)/dt = -K P(t)$

I think this needs to separate variables.

I want to solve for $P(t)$ then plot the solution as function of $t$ while assuming that $K = 0.001$.

Comment: Look up DSolve and NDSolve in the documentation center.  There are examples of plotting there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can get you started, but also check what @MichaelE2 suggested.

```
DSolve[P'[t] == -k P[t], P[t], t]

{{P[t] -> E^(-k t) C[1]}}

P[t_] := Exp[-k t]

 Plot[{P[t] /. k -> 1, P[t] /. k -> 2, P[t] /. k -> 3, 
  P[t] /. k -> 4}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"
```

[image: Plot]

Have fun with Mathematica.

Cheers!!!